# Model cannot be accessed during validation in AngularJS form?

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to access the model of a form element that is using validation (e.g. `ng-minlength`).
It seems that the model is undefined until the validation passes.

Is this the intended behaviour? How can I access a non-valid model?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ybdssvt5/

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
   <form name="myForm">
     <input type="text" ng-minlength="5" ng-model="formData.email" required/>
     <div>EMAIL length: {{ formData.email.length }}</div>
   </form>
</div>
```

EMAIL length cannot be displayed until validation passes.

Comment: that's how validation works, it prevents setting model before input data is valid, so `formData.email` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you can plug in a controller and assign a default value,

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', [])
.controller('appCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.form.email = '';   
});
```

This is a dirty way, but you can improvise from here easily.

Also you need to add ng-controller="appCtrl" to your ng-app div or form.